# How to make a script with Autokey that toggles maximize terminal window?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Linux Mint 19.2 and I'm able to create a shortcut in the keyboard utility under:

Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows > Toggle Maximize State

This however binds the keys to all windows. I want to only bind it to the terminal window.

I tried doing this with the excellent autokey program (https://github.com/autokey) but had no luck getting it to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?